# Using Serilog.Sinks.MsSqlServer with Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, serilog, serilog.sinks.mssqlserver

I'm using Entity Framework Core and code first. And I'd like to start logging to my database with *Serilog.Sinks.MsSqlServer*.

Since I may want to query the logs, I'm thinking about creating the *Logs* table via EF Core, and then telling Serilog not to create the table.

Does anyone have experience with creating the *Logs* table with Entity Framework? I haven't been able to find any examples of this. I don't know if *Serilog.Sinks.MsSqlServer* has tools for querying the logs. Does it make sense to create the table and then to query it myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all it can make sense to create the table with EF Core to query it. I have done that before to query some logs (e.g in an admin dashboard) and its quite easy to do so:

**1. Log Entity Definition:**

```cs
public class LogEntry
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public string MessageTemplate { get; set; }
    public string Level { get; set; }
    public DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; }
    public string? Exception { get; set; }
    public string? Properties { get; set; }
    public string? LogEvent { get; set; }
}
```

This class has all the properties the Serilog sink needs to write your logs to the database.

**2. `DbContext` configuration:**

```cs
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<LogEntry> Logs { get; set; }

    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) :base(options)
    {
        
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(typeof(Program).Assembly);
    }
}
```

I always use `ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly()` to configure my database entities so I also need to create a configuration class for the `LogEntry` that looks like this:

```cs
public class LogEntryConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<LogEntry>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<LogEntry> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("Logs");
        
        builder.HasKey(p => p.Id);

        builder.Property(p => p.Exception)
            .IsRequired(false);
        
        builder.Property(p => p.Properties)
            .IsRequired(false);
        
        builder.Property(p => p.LogEvent)
            .IsRequired(false);
        
        builder.Property(p => p.TimeStamp)
            .HasColumnType("datetime");
        
        builder.Property(p => p.Level)
            .HasMaxLength(16);
    }
}
```

Of course you do not have to do the configuration like this but the properties need to be configured like this.

**3. Configure the Serilog sink:**

```cs
var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .ReadFrom.Configuration(builder.Configuration)
    .Enrich.FromLogContext()
    .WriteTo.MSSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"),
        new MSSqlServerSinkOptions()
    {
        AutoCreateSqlDatabase = false,
        AutoCreateSqlTable = false,
        TableName = "Logs"
    })
    .CreateLogger();
builder.Logging.ClearProviders();
builder.Logging.AddSerilog(logger);
```

For this example I configured Serilog from code but it can also be done in the `appsettings.json` as described in the documentation [here](https://github.com/serilog-mssql/serilog-sinks-mssqlserver#json-microsoftextensionsconfiguration).
The important things here are `AutoCreateSqlDatabase = false`, `AutoCreateSqlTable = false` so the sink does not try to create the `Logs` table by itself.

After that the sink writes to our created `Logs` table and you can query the table with EF Core like you would do with an other table.